# How to get Get Amazon User Name / User ID from Opsworks deployment hooks?

Tags: chef, opsworks

I'm trying to convert a Capistrano deploy script to OpsWorks recipes. I'm doing so far so good, except for Slack integration. In the Capistrano script, it says

> John Doe is deploying FooProject from Master to Production

via [Slack](https://slack.com/), alerting the team if someone is doing deployment somewhere.

Currently, what I can do is create a `deploy/before_migrate.rb` to say

> Deploying FooProject to Production

Is there a way to know the IAM User ID / User Name of the person invoking the deploy?

(If you notice, I also need to get the branch being deployed, but I'd reserve that for another post.)

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It can be accessed via

```
deploying_user = node['deploy']['foo_app']['deploying_user']
```

The resulting string will be of the format

```
arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/johndoe
```

Where `XXXXXXXXXXXX` is your Amazon IAM ID, and `johndoe` is your IAM Username.